# printing pairs adjacent of of a character string

Tags: c++, string

Hello everyone I am  struggling to find the right way to print  pairs  adjacent  of a character string and duplicated, for example, if I want to print the pairs adjacent like this example (abcd) (a and b) pair adjacent because they are next to each other so print them and duplicated them after that move on to the next pairs adjacent it is ( c and d ) and also print them and duplicated
I have found a way to solve this example;
but I did not get the right way to solve if I have more than 4 char  Or the length of the string consists of odd numbers
for example if I have   abcde >>> ab ab cd cd ee it is only dublicated the last char without the char before it ;

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    string name = "abcd";

    cout<<name<< " >>>> ";
    char* ptr = &name[0];
    char* ptr1 = &name[1];


     for (int i =0; i<name.size(); i++){
        if (ptr==&name[0])
            ptr1=&name[1];
        for (int j=0;j<name.size()/2;j++){
            cout<<*ptr<<*ptr1;

        }
        ptr+=2;
        ptr1+=2;



    }










    return 0;
}
```

and the out but is

```
abcd >>>> ababcdcd
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. The simple exaple "abcd >> ababcdcd" doesn't clearly explain the desired objective.

Comment: for example, if i want to print the pairs adjacent like this example (abcd)  (a and b) pair adjacent because they are next to each other so print them   and  duplicated them after that  move on to the next pairs adjacent it is ( c and d ) and also print them and dublicated

Comment: What happens when you have an odd number of characters in your string?

Comment: it prints the last char alone and it dublicted like this way abcde >>> ab ab cd cd ee

Comment: Please [edit] the post and add those details. They should not be lost in comments.

Comment: ok. thanks, I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

You made your program a bit more complex than it needs to be. Here's one way it can be simplified.

1. Gather pairs of characters in the loop.
2. Deal with the case where there are odd number of characters in the string.
3. Increment the loop index by two in each iteration.

You can also provide `name` as the first argument to the program so you don't have to edit it and build it for different inputs.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   string name = argv[1];

   cout<<name<< " >>>> ";

   for (int i =0; i<name.size(); i += 2)
   {
      char c1 = name[i];
      char c2 = c1;
      if ( i+1 != name.size() )
      {
         c2 = name[i+1];
         cout << c1 << c2;
      }
      cout << c1 << c2;
   }
   cout << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're right this lock simple and better, but still, the same issue when the length of the string consists of odd numbers the last char only duplicated without pairs, for example, abcde >>  the output is >> ab ab cd cd ee ;  << like you see the last char which is (e) only duplicated.   the output should be >> ab ab cd cd de de ;